# Web part giving 401 on public facing site

Tags: web-part, 401

I have created a Blog in my site and change its layout. I'm using a webpart which is giving 401 error on public facing site.

My Code is:

```
public void CustomBlogLayout()
{
    SPSite thisSite = SPContext.Current.Site;
    using (SPWeb targetWeb = thisSite.AllWebs["/en-us/blogs/"])
    {
        SPList Forms = targetWeb.Lists["Posts"];
        SPQuery qry = new SPQuery();
        qry.Query = @"<Query>" +
                        "<OrderBy>" +
                            "<FieldRef Ascending='FALSE' Name='Modified' />" +
                            "</OrderBy>" +
                     "</Query>";
        SPListItemCollection SPLIC = Forms.GetItems(qry);
        LiteralControl print = null;
        string tlink = string.Empty;
        foreach (SPListItem item in SPLIC)
        {
            tlink = "/en-us/blogs/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?&ID=" + item.ID;

            string[] authorInfo = item["Author"].ToString().Split(';');
            string authorId = authorInfo[0];
            string author = authorInfo[1].Replace("#", string.Empty);
            string alink = "/en-us/blogs/_layouts/userdisp.aspx?ID=" + Convert.ToInt32(authorId);

            string body = item["Body"].ToString();

            print = new LiteralControl("<div class='ms-PostTitle' ><a href=" + tlink + " >" + item["Title"].ToString() + "</a></div>" +
                                        "<div class='ms-PostFooter' > by " + "<a href=" + alink + " >" + author + "</a>\t" + "on " + item["Modified"].ToString() + "</div>" +
                                        "<div class='ms-PostBody' >" + item["Body"].ToString() + "</div>"
                                       );
            this.Controls.Add(print);
        }
    } 
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

The thisSite.AllWebs is loading all webs so unless all of the allow anonymous access this will fail.

Replace it with

```
using (SPWeb targetWeb = thisSite.OpenWeb("/en-us/blogs/"))
```

or

```
SPWeb targetWeb = SPContext.Current.Web
```

Comment: Hi Per, Thanks again for your support. I have test both but same "401 UNAUTHORIZED" message. Even i remove all code and deploye wepart with no code it shows same error. I don't whats the problem? From last 1 week i am working on this issue but no success. I'm in big trouble now. :'(

Comment: I also noticed that even i delete webpart from default.aspx page it still shows "401 UNAUTHORIZED" message on public facing site. However, posts are accessible even i add web part or not. check this [link](http://wwwqa.nextdocs.com/en-us/blogs/default.aspx) this is showing 401 and posts page is working fine [link](http://wwwqa.nextdocs.com/en-us/blogs/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=5)

Comment: I can't see the web part on the post page.

Comment: Yes Webpart is not on posts page and it is accessible i have also removed webpart from default.aspx page but it still giving 401. :(

Answer (score 0):

SPContext is a user aware object that will give you security exceptions in a lot of cases when used on an public facing web site without any authentication.

Create new SPSite/SPWeb objects instead:

```
using( var site = new SPSite( yourUrlHere ))
{
    using (var web = site.OpenWeb( yourUrl ))
    { rest of your code here... }
```

Answer (score 0):

use RunWithElevatedPrivileges delegation

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {

                using (SPSite site = new SPSite(bla bla..)
                {  
                    //my code
                }
            });
```